# Unable to access objects datamember, despite showing its exsistence in console.log. Attempted access returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have a array of anonymous functions that are constructors, they take a parameter, then use it to build a var to this.

```
var template = [
     function (model){ this.html = "blah" + model.something},
     function (model){ this.html = "blah" + model.something},
]
```

I loop through the array and construct each function into an object using the new keyword.

```
template.foreach( template => template = new template(model))
```

This seems to work because when I console.log it shows template as a list of objects with data member this.html, and its populated correctly.

However, when I try to access template[0].html it returns undefined.

When I do `typeof` on an element of the list it says function, yet the browser shows it as an object, and most importantly when I do template[0].html it returns as undefined despite showing it when I console log the list.

Answer (score 0):

1. it should be `forEach()` instead of `foreach()`
2. You should always return something in your function.

This is very strange way to use `this` it is because when you store function in array, the `this` is referencing the object where you call this function.

Comment: Why should you always return something? You can use a function as a object in js. So the function is a constructor, loading the object with this keyword

Comment: It would be nice if they let me edit my own question, then I could change the foreach to forEach. I can only edit my comments

Comment: Ok. You are right about function are not required to return sth. But then you will have an undefined value when you do `template[0].html` since the is nothing returned in template[0](which is a function)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that forEach is not changing the array that is being iterated, it is just iterating it. If you want to return an array of already created objects you can use other function like map:

```
const myObjectArray = template.map(t => new t(model));
```

Now you can access myObjectArray[0].html

Take care that myObjectArray is a new array and template is not changed.

By the way, having a variable called template that holds an array is not a good practice, better call it templateArray or templates (make it clear that it is an array)

Comment: This is how I meant to type it                                                                          templates.forEach( (template, index) => templates[index] = new template(model))           which works here but not in my program.... ah

Comment: Thank you A. Llorente, can I map a function to itself. I do not want to create a new var because I will not need it

Comment: Yes you can but it is not recommended, it is much easier to follow code that do not reassign variables, so you have your array with templates and your array with objects. It is not a problem to have two variables, the engine can handle that and much more ;)

Comment: Its still not working, I tried defining temp to the line above this and it still has temp as undefined. Further I tried with using temp as a list and pushing each new object to the list, still undefined.                                                                                                       getModel().then( model => {var temp = templates.map(template => new template(model)) })  
console.log(temp[0].html, typeof templates[0], templates)   // undefined function, list of functions

Comment: If I run this code in console it works as expected:
var templates = [
     function (model){ this.html = "blah" + model.something},
     function (model){ this.html = "blah" + model.something},
];
var temp =  templates.map(template => new template({})); 
console.log(temp[0].html, typeof templates[0], templates);
// blahundefined function (2) [ƒ, ƒ]

Comment: This was a symptom of another issue. I was returning a promise and the code had not yet resolved the promise. Thank you for your help and patience